# Стоит ли переводить вопросы и ответы с англоязычного SO?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, stackoverflow, перевод-содержимого

Наполнение русскоязычного SO по тегу [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) довольно слабое. Я преподаю С++, но у студентов есть определённые проблемы с чтением материала на английском языке. Конечно же, я всегда советую учиться английскому языку, но это не спасает от необходимости разъяснять им вещи, с переводом которых у них возникают проблемы. Нередко это материал с SO.

У меня есть желание перевести некоторые основные вопросы по [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) с англоязычного ресурса, и самостоятельно ответить на них, скомпоновав ответ на русском языке из нескольких чужих на английском языке, а также собственных знаний по теме. Тем не менее, из правил ресурса мне не очевидно, этично ли так делать. Не будет ли это сочтено за погоню за рейтингом, учитывая, что переводы популярных вопросов, скорее всего, тоже будут популярны?

Полагается ли, что большинство пользователей достаточно хорошо разбирается с английским языком (или google translate), что может сначала поискать ответы на англоязычном SO?

Считается ли, что русскоязычный ресурс нужен только для того, чтобы русскоязычным пользователям было легче *задавать новые вопросы*?

Comment: Если не было задано тематического вопроса, не стоит.

Comment: Прошло полтора года, но мы по-прежнему будем рады переводам хороших вопросов. )

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Миссия Stack Overflow — организация знаний. В правилах ясно указано: задать вопрос и самостоятельно на него ответить, даже сразу — это нормально и всячески приветствуется. За это даже даётся отдельный значок. Дескать, если вы считаете, что ваша информация будет полезна кому-то ещё, то поделиться ей — ваш святой долг.

Про Stack Overflow на различных языках ведутся споры о целесообразности, но в конце концов идея создания та же: предоставить информацию. Если кто-то не знает английского (или не знает достаточно хорошо), то пусть лучше будет Stack Overflow на русском языке, пусть и с последствиями типа фрагментации аудитории, чем ничего взамен.

Перевод важных и полезных вопросов, очевидно, вписывается в миссию предоставлять информацию. Со временем вопросы польются рекой, на сайте зарегистрируется ещё больше профессионалов, и необходимость в переводе отпадёт. А до тех пор можно немного и попереводить.

Должен заметить, что даже при написании ответа на часть естественным образом заданных вопросов вы можете воспользоваться Гуглом и обнаружить, что, по сути, написали то же самое, что уже есть на англоязычном Stack Overflow. Вот и получился "перевод".

С точки зрения лицензии всё чисто: лицензия на контент позволяет свободно переносить информацию между сайтами, коль скоро указан первоисточник.

Что касается меня, то у меня в планах перевести некоторые "каноничные" вопросы с большого Stack Overflow, которые имеют инфраструктурное значение: некоторые однообразные вопросы появляются постоянно, и часто удобно сослаться на универсальный детальный и развёрнутый ответ, а не расписывать одно и то же для каждого посетителя. Например, в рамках этого плана я перевёл вопрос и ответ "[Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)"

Если вы боитесь обвинений в "воровстве" репутации, то можете отмечать свои вопросы и ответы как "общие". Но опасения безосновательны: перевод, особенно качественный перевод — это тоже труд, и у вас есть полное право на достойное вознаграждение.

Comment: Хотелось добавить, на сколько я знаю, на Stack Overflow на португальском вопросы чаще переводятся в обратном направлении, то есть если кто-то задает интересный вопрос на португальском и такого вопроса нет на английском, то после получения ответа он переносится на англоязычный форум. Обратная ситуация происходит реже.

Comment: Stack Overflow на русском — сайт вопросов и ответов для программистов.

Answer (score -9):

## По моему мнению - не стоит

Stack Overflow на русском — сайт **вопросов** и **ответов** для программистов.
И я вижу его именно таким.

Именно такое описание мне вернул Google:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть раньше, было и так - **организация знаний**, но сюда по тенденции, люди в основном идут **задать вопрос**, с надеждой **получить ответ**, а не сделать перевод.

Когда вопрос будет задан кем то, то можно и перевод.
Или хотя бы автор сам столкнется с проблемой, задаст вопрос.
Дождется ответом от сообщества, потом разместит свой.
Дождется ответов, так как дав ответ сразу, кто то уже может не разместить свой ответ, ввиду вполне уже подходящего ответа, по его мнению.
Так мы, сообщество, можем потерять ценные идеи, мысли, доводы...

*...Это все мое сугубо личное мнение...*

**UPD**

> Проблема с переводами в том, что подобные вопросы не являются «настоящими»—люди, которым нужен ответ, могут не знать правильную терминологию и поэтому не ясно поможет ли им перевод (смогут ли они его найти)
> (c) [jfs](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs)

*..На все 120% согласен..*

Comment: Спасибо за крайне интересную идею! Подскажите, похожа ли архитектура решения на процесс запроса документации ([см. тут](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/))?

Comment: Также, подскажите, каким образом, как вы считаете, это вписывается в модель [вопрос с ответом самому себе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: Поправьте, если я не верно понял. Пример процесса выглядит следующим образом. Участник нашел интересный вопрос для перевода. Перевел вопрос и ответ (или только вопрос?) и публикует его. Публикуется только сам вопрос, со специальными атрибутами, а ответ становится доступен лишь некоторой группе участников (к примеру, ограничение по репутации по меткам вопроса). Эта группа добавляет свои идеи и правки в ответ и после N–подтверждений ответ публикуется. Верно?

Comment: При этом, к примеру, вопрос может быть авторским, а ответ должен быть общим? Или, к примеру, ответ будет авторским, если никто ничего не дополнил?

Comment: К сожалению, статистика доступна только пользователям с большим количеством репутации, поэтому я не могу судить, зачем люди приходят на сайт. Но всё же программистам важнее получить ответ, а не задать вопрос. Более того, вопросы-переводы без ответов будут разбавлять вопросы людей, которым ответ нужен срочно. Поэтому я считаю, что переводы (вопроса и ответов) всё же нужны.

Comment: Чтобы другие пользователи могли добавить свои ответы, есть задержка на выбор лучшего ответа, эта проблема уже решена. Переведённые тексты с меньшей вероятностью будут возникать в Google, потому что написаны переводчиками, понимающими предметную область на достаточном уровне и знакомыми с терминологией. Но для этого есть другой механизм, закрытые вопросы-дупликаты, и эта проблема тоже решена. Поэтому я всё ещё не понимаю вашу точку зрения. Был бы рад услышать чуть более конструктивные аргументы.

Comment: Если люди хотят переводить, то *запрещать переводы не стоит*, если они явно ссылки содержат на оригинал (так как перевод может не отражать адекватно текущее состояние или в будущем могут существенные отличия появится)—подобные вопросы вероятно удовлетворяют правилам сами по себе (вне зависимости от того являются они переводами или нет) . Проблема с переводами в том, что подобные вопросы не являются «настоящими»—люди, которым нужен ответ, могут не знать правильную терминологию и поэтому не ясно поможет ли им перевод (смогут ли они его найти).

Comment: ...(продолжение) Можно посмотреть на количество просмотров уже существующих переводов—если они популярны, то есть если они помогают людям найти сайт, то переводы полезны—люди не могут задать «настоящий» вопрос, о возникшей у них проблеме, если они не знают о сайте.

Comment: С другой стороны, если большинство программистов уже знают о сайте, то искусственные вопросы (переводы) не нужны. Нужен доступ к аналитике большого и русского Stack Overflow, чтобы сравнить пропорции посещений русскоязычных программистов. По моим впечатлениям, по порядку величины, посещение русского SO и так достаточно (я могу ошибаться)

Comment: смогут ли они его найти (c) jfs - В точку!

Comment: Добавил в ответ, надеюсь , вы не против?

Comment: Вот вам пример "ненастоящего" вопроса - сам спросил, сам ответил, 7700 просмотров за 10 месяцев. Вроде находят. =) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472

Comment: я лично захожу на русский SO с одной целью - почитать вопросы и, возможно, в меру своих сил, помочь кому-то в решении проблемы. В связи с этим, для меня вообще не представляют никакого интереса искусственные вопросы с ответами переведенные на русский язык. Это таки не база знаний, а сервис помощи. Имхо.