# Какие вопросы про Git целесообразно перевести с английского?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, перевод-содержимого

Как показывает недавнее [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/70/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-so?rq=1), переводить самые популярные вопросы с качественными ответами это хорошо, полезно и соответствует политике stackoverflow.

Мне интересен Git и я его неплохо понимаю. Хочу понемногу заняться переводами самых ценных вопросов. Сам многие из них проштудировал на английском, когда только знакомился с Git. Там часто полезные варианты решения размазаны по десятку ответов, так что работа будет наполовину редакторская.

Вопрос: что из этого в первую очередь перевести? Вот [топ-30 по голосам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=30). Я за вот такой список. Эти ситуации рано или поздно, но возникают у всех пользователей Git:

1. [How to undo the last commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commit)
2. [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)
3. [Revert to a previous Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Какие у меня критерии для выбора вопросов:

1. Требования к вопросу:

   - Проблема действительно часто встречается.
   - Либо это нечто оригинальное.
2. Ответ не только предлагает рецепт, а дает фундаментальное объяснение решения.

#### Переведено на данный момент:

- [Как добавлять файлы в Git по их номеру в отчете `git status`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430471/)
- [Как показать N последних тегов (меток)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429704/)

Comment: [перевод] — это мета-метка, правилами они запрещены. Ну и критерии соверешнно непонятны: 1) никто не мешает запостить непереведённые ответы; 2) часть ответов на непереведённые вопросы заимствуют информацию из ответов на других языках и т. п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретный список вопросов для перевода не приведу, вам, как специалисту, должно быть виднее. Лишних вопросов в Топе нет, как по мне.

Добавлю только, что хорошим источником вопросов для перевода часто является запрос [Posts that are the target of the most duplicate closures](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/315074/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures) — если на вопрос часто ссылаются, когда закрывают другие вопросы как дубликаты, это хороший признак, что вопрос интересует многих. Можно использовать этот запрос в дополнение к простой сортировке по голосам.

Я сейчас немного модифицировал запрос, и теперь можно фильтровать по меткам. Например, вот [список вопросов по метке *git*](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/315074/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures?TagName=git). Количество дубликатов не такое большое — видимо, те, кто пользуется Git, обычно умеют гуглить. :)

Comment: О, спасибо за наводку, отличная идея. В топе конечно все вопросы нужные, но переводить-то можно только по очереди.