# Самореклама в описании меток

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Недавно отклонил правку, предложенную пользователем @Nick Volynkin к вики метки [git-add](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-add). Правка заключалась в том, что ссылки на часто задаваемые вопросы были изменены таким образом, что не просто вели на вопрос, но и помогали пользователю @Nick Volynkin возможность без особого напряга заработать знаки Диктор, Усилитель и Публицист, которые даются за то, что ссылку, расшаренную пользователем открыли определённое количество раз с уникальных IP. Это определённо не было случайностью - кроме этих изменений правка [ничего не содержала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/430476/revisions). Позже пользователь @Nick Volynkin всё-таки получил подтверждение этой правки от другого пользователя.

Итак, мой вопрос к сообществу заключается в следующем: как вы считаете, этично ли так поступать? С одной стороны, автор качественного описания метки заслуживает поощрения за свой труд. С другой же, это сильно похоже на жульничество: ведь знаки Диктор, Усилитель и Публицист (по моему скромному мнению) предназначены для поощрения продвижения ru.SO на внешних ресурсах. Хотелось бы также услышать мнение пользователем @Nick Volynkin на этот счёт.

И вдогонку: нужны ли вообще метки [git-add](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-add), [git-commit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit), [git-reset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reset), [git-checkout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout), [git-reflog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reflog), созданные и продвигаемые пользователем @Nick Volynkin как здесь, так и на большом SO? Нужна ли такая точная категоризация вопросов про Git и будут ли новые вопросы задаваться с этими метками? Особой популярностью эти метки не пользуются, как на ru.SO, так и на SO вопросы по ним задавал только пользователь @Nick Volynkin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Хорошо, что вы, fori1ton, об этом спросили. Мне самому интересно, как коллеги оценивают мою работу и нужна ли она вообще кому-то. Вот и выясним.

Уважаемые коллеги, тут довольно много текста, но я расставил осмысленные заголовки, так что вы можете пролистать и прочитать только те разделы, которые вам интересны.

## Зачем и почему я всё это делаю

### Почему

Некоторое время назад обсуждался вопрос [Стоит ли переводить вопросы и ответы с англоязычного SO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70/181472). Ответ был положительный, сообщество одобрило эту идею.

Я пока что компетентен в небольшом круге тем: Java и Git. К тому же неплохо знаю английский и имею некоторые навыки технического писательства. Поэтому задача показалась мне интересной. По Java и так много энтузиастов (которые еще и гораздо опытнее меня), а вот Git на мой взгляд обычно всем скучен. По крайней мере, те популярные вопросы, которые уже были на RU.SO, касались концептуальных вопросов: в чем различия, как организовать рабочий процесс. А вот **детальных руководств** (которых на EN.SO есть около полусотни популярных) **не было**.

### Зачем

**Всё это приводит к тому, что я могу внести существенный вклад в развитие StackOverflow на русском языке, переводя лучшие вопросы с EN.SO и других ресурсов.** И первая тема, которой я могу заняться - Git.

### Как

Задал вопрос [Какие вопросы про Git целесообразно перевести с английского?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366/181472) Начал понемногу работать. На деле оказывается, что я ни разу не перевел вопрос и ответ дословно. Там всегда есть несколько вариантов, в них где-то есть ошибки, какая-то информация относится к устаревшей версии. В процессе написания ответа я прорабатываю от трех до десяти аналогичных вопросов на английском, включая все ответы и все комментарии, плюс один-два источника документации.

**Обычно на один ответ уходит часа три-четыре работы**. Но [последний, как раз тот, что я добавил в описание метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431839/181472), занял уже больше 10 часов. Оказалось, что есть много тонкостей, о которых я даже не подозревал на момент публикации первой версии. Несколько пользователей указали мне на мои ошибки или задали уточняющие вопросы. Вопрос выдержал два десятка правок.

### Вот что я сделал на сегодняшний день:

[Как показать N последних тегов (меток)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429704/181472)
[Как добавлять файлы в Git по их номеру в отчете `git status`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430471/181472)
[Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472)
[В чем разница между git add ., add -A, add -u и add *?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431839/181472)
[Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472)

## Почему и как я пишу описания меток

В процессе работы над вопросами я пришел к выводу, что к хорошим вопросам необходимы еще и релевантные метки. Поэтому создал вопрос [Как правильно составлять описание метки (tag wiki)? Что туда включать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/527/181472). Большой популярностью он не пользовался, но сам для себя я разработал шаблон хорошего содержания метки. Этот шаблон в том числе включал две категории:

- **Часто задаваемые вопросы**. Те проблемы, с которыми обычно сталкиваются рано или поздно все. **Цель - повысить полезность от хороших ответов и понизить количество дублей**.
- **Рекомендуемые вопросы**. То, что по субъективному мнению авторов описания метки имеет важное значение для концептуального понимания темы. **Цель - дать человеку более полное понимание темы и тем самым понизить количество будущих ошибок.** Например, про [git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) важно понимать, [как устроен коммит, и является он патчем/дельтой или снимком (snapshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5176225/2790048).

По этим шаблонам я уже сделал описания знаков [git-commit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit), [git-add](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-add), [git-flow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-flow), [git-branch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-branch) и планирую сделать их еще для полутора десятков.

## Зачем вообще нужны детальные/конкретные метки,

> созданные и продвигаемые пользователем @Nick Volynkin как здесь, так и на большом SO

### Зачем нужны сами конкретные метки

Почитайте, например, вот это обсуждение на мете: [Can we get rid of [git-something] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266254/2790048). Там выделяются 4 основных причины (перевожу, **выделение авторское**, *комментарии переводчика курсивом*):

`<перевод>`

- **Для экспертов по меткам**. [Как подчеркивает Cupcake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags#comment64486_266221), конкретные метки позволяют быстрее находить дубликаты вопросов.
  *Да, дельных ответов про Git у нас пока мало, можно и наизусть запомнить. Но сообщество растет, база знаний ширится и если сразу не задать четкую структуру, то будет накапливаться бардак и хаос. Мы ведь хотим меньше дублей?*
- **Для обычных пользователей**: Конкретные метки позволяют проще находить подходящие вопросы, когда пользователь хочет найти больше информации по каждой конкретной команде.
  *Я лично этим часто пользуюсь на EN.SO. Начинаю с чтения tag wiki и далее по популярным вопросам.*
- **Для спрашивающих**: Если конкретные метки убрать, то большинству спрашивающих останется только одна метка [git]. Не имея возможности использовать соответствующие осмысленные метки, пользователи наверняка начнут использовать некорректные *обобщенные* метки вроде [команда] и [репозиторий]. Удаление конкретных меток приведет к использованию других, ошибочных.
  *Моя любимая метка - [ошибка]*

[image]

- **Для отвечающих**: Как подчеркнул megawac, отвечающие могут отслеживать специфические метки, потому что именно по ним бывают интересные им вопросы про Git. Зонтичная метка [git] слишком широка.
  *megawac:* Я отслеживаю `git-tree-filter` и некоторые другие узкие темы...
  *Совершенно верно. Вопросы с только меткой [git] обычно заключаются в том, что человек не читал документацию. [Они вызывают злость.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/535/181472)  Вопросы с [git-fsck] или [git-filter-branch] обычно требуют хороших знаний Git, shell, и чего-нибудь еще. Они реально интересные.*
- Описания конкретных меток будут потеряны, если метки удалить или слить.
  *Или никогда не будут созданы.*

`</перевод>`

- **Еще для экспертов** - возможность заработать дополнительные знаки. Например, очень уважаемый мной эксперт [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=badges) имеет только по git-меткам знаки за git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-diff, git-pull, git-tag, git-fork, git-bash, github-api, commit, gitignore, git-flow, githooks, rebase, bitbucket, git-submodules, egit, git-merge, git-commit...

### Чем ценны описания конкретных меток

Тем, что они представляют собой краткую документацию по предмету конкретной метки. В случае с Git это команда, концепция (как git flow) или связанный инструмент (как GitHub). Если конкретной метки не будет, то в описание общей метки всё впихнуть не получится. Придется оставить только ссылки, а "просто ссылка" на SO не приветствуется.

Как неоднократно повторялось, [миссия Stack Overflow — организация знаний](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/71/181472).  На мой взгляд, описания меток - тоже способ организации знаний и я его использую.

## Про пользователя @NickVolynkin

### Вопросы по конкретным меткам

> нужны ли вообще метки ..., созданные и продвигаемые пользователем @Nick Volynkin ... здесь

Я уже объяснил, почему они нужны и важны, и особенно здесь и на этом этапе развития сообщества.

> нужны ли вообще метки ..., созданные и продвигаемые пользователем @Nick Volynkin ... и на большом SO**

Вы можете аргументировать свои слова или просто пальцем в небо? На данный момент, я на EN.SO создал одну метку из примерно полусотни. Вся основная структура создана до меня.

> как на ru.SO, ... вопросы по ним задавал только пользователь @Nick Volynkin.

Опять вы голословны.

До моего вмешательства существовали метки github, gitlab, git-commit, git-svn, tortoise-git (и ошибочный turtoise) и несколько других. По ним задавали вопросы.

> будут ли новые вопросы задаваться с этими метками?

Вот новый вопрос с недавно созданной мной меткой [git-branch]: [Работа одноврменно с двумя ветками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431546/181472). Метку сразу использовал ОП. Вывод: конкретные метки используют разные люди, не только я.

Да, я просмотрел большинство старых вопросов и отредактировал часть из них их, добавив соответствующие конкретные метки. Цель была в том, чтобы по каждой метке реально можно было найти выборку лучших ответов по соответствующей теме. По многим меткам уже можно.

> **так и на SO** вопросы по ним задавал только пользователь @Nick Volynkin.

Простите мне мой французский, но это несусветная чушь. Посмотрите хотя бы на этот вопрос, найдите там меня хоть где-нибудь на странице: [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179123/2790048). Теперь посмотрите на топ любой метки по Git. Даже в первых сотнях там нет моих вопросов и ответов.

### Про правку

Вообще, предыдущая редакция описания метки тоже была сделана мной с нуля. И метка была создана за пару дней до этого тоже мной.

> кроме этих изменений правка ничего не содержала.

**Неверно**. В правку были добавлены два новых вопроса. Один из них я только что написал, да. Можете считать что я его пиарю. Но это качественный вопрос-руководство и я отвечаю за его качество и достоверность. В этом описании есть и ответы других авторов. Как я их нашел? Просто прочитал с полсотни самых популярных вопросов и ответов и выбрал лучшее.

Да, все вопросы выбраны только мной на основе только моего субъективного мнения. Почему так? Потому что на данный момент только я пожелал внести вклад в создание метки. У нас тут на SO технократия. Имеете свое аргументированное мнение - добро пожаловать в редакторы, там еще много меток без описания.

### Про знаки Диктор, Усилитель и Публицист.

В указанной Вами правке я действительно заменил более ранние ссылки на другой формат, который мне кажется более лаконичным. И эти ссылки удобнее забирать с конкретных постов, так как они получаются по нажатию кнопки <kbd>L</kbd> на посте. (Осваиваю управление SO с клавиатуры).

Я только сейчас задался вопросом, как вообще работает эта реферальная система и как считаются переходы. Суть в том, что в такой ссылке есть мой user id. Поможет ли мне это зарабатывать какие-то знаки? Ссылки-то внутри RU.SO расположены. Я задал вопрос об этом на мете и получил ответ модератора: [Does announcer badge count increase when link is opened from inside StackExchange network?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297924/2790048)

> **Ответ модератора: НЕТ, ссылки внутри SE не увеличивают счетчик реферальных ссылок**

### Без особого напряга

> возможность без особого напряга заработать знаки

Про знаки уже всё понятно. Давайте-ка сравним возможности зарабатывания чего-нибудь еще за счет вопросов на RU.SO.

Вот я недавно [ответил на дурацкий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060180/2790048) на EN.SO. Заработал 45 репутации за 15 минут - это 180 репы в час.

Вспомним мой последний вопрос-ответ про `git add`. 10 часов, на данный момент 150 репутации в сумме. Это 15 репы в час.

Напомню, это вообще нормальные рабочие часы квалифицированного труда программиста-джуниора. Я не думаю, что об этом можно сказать "без особого напряга". Тем более, это не зарплата какая-нибудь, а пиксели. Максимум материальной пользы, который я могу извлечь - это ускорить решение собственного ответа за счет назначения награды, на которую потрачу заработанную репутацию. Ну еще при трудоустройстве могу похвастаться.

**Для меня смысл моей работы здесь - внести свой вклад в базу знаний теми навыками, которые у меня есть.** Знаки и репутация вторичны, хотя они, конечно, делают процесс интереснее.

Comment: Он не мог бы Вам написать, ЛС ведь нет на SO. Т.е. он использовал правильный формат, судя по тому, что Nicolas говорит. Я бы не стал обижаться - человек просто не понял Вас, вот и опубликовал пост. Я надеюсь Вас это не очень задело, Вы проделали поистине большой объём работ, за что Вам можно только сказать спасибо

Comment: @ixSci во-первых, есть чаты. Можно создать чат и прислать приглашение. Во-вторых, когда не понял, нужно спросить: "Скажите, а что и зачем вы делаете?". Спасибо Вам за поддержку, мой объем работ пока что совсем ещё небольшой.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный и аргументированный ответ. Действительно, вышло недопонимание. Прошу меня простить за обвинения (если это можно так назвать) в "создании и продвижении" меток - действительно, на SO эти метки были и до вас, я просто неправильно собирал по ним статистику. Ваш труд по переводу и написанию авторских ответов однозначно полезен для сообщества и заслуживает благодарности.

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за разъяснение принципа работы реферальной системы и упоминание шорткатов. Не могли бы вы указать, где в справке они описаны? У меня не получилось использовать кнопку L для получения ссылки на что бы то ни было. Где, как и когда её следует нажимать? Может, стоит об этом отдельный пост написать?

Comment: @fori1ton извинения приняты. :) Про шорткаты: профиль - настройки - Горячие клавиши. Потом `?` на любой странице для справки. Позволяет рулить SO с клавиатуры, правда не везде все работает, что хотелось бы. Раскладка только английская, в кириллицу не может.

Comment: @fori1ton получилось? Сомневаюсь, нужен ли пост об этом, клавиатурных маньяков немного и они обычно сами научаются всему.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает. Действительно, удобная штука. Странно, что не обратил внимание на эту настройку раньше.

Comment: О-о-о, ещё один любитель длиннопостов... Так держать! =)

Comment: Поправил описание метки. Учитывая, что реферральные ссылки бесполезны, удалил реферральную часть. См. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/430476/revisions

Comment: @Discord Ок, отлично. Сам не стал править, чтобы попусту не дергать проверяющих. А конструктивная правка пока не назрела.

Answer (score 2):

> Правка заключалась в том, что ссылки на часто задаваемые вопросы были изменены таким образом, что не просто вели на вопрос, но и помогали пользователю @Nick Volynkin возможность без особого напряга заработать знаки Диктор, Усилитель и Публицист, которые даются за то, что ссылку, расшаренную пользователем открыли определённое количество раз с уникальных IP.

На мой взгляд, тут надо смотреть по релевантности и полезности материалов. Если в этом плане всё хорошо, то почему бы нет? Вряд ли много пользователей могут навыдумывать полезных статей на какую-либо тему. А если кто-то может, то знак за это вполне заслуженный.

> ведь знаки Диктор, Усилитель и Публицист (по моему скромному мнению) предназначены для поощрения продвижения ru.SO на внешних ресурсах.

Интересное мнение. Как-то даже не смотрел на них с этой стороны.

> нужны ли вообще метки [git-add](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-add), [git-commit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit), [git-reset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reset), [git-checkout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout), [git-reflog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reflog)

Я видел несколько предлагаемых правок меток, где они добавлялись к вопросу. Нажал пропустить (именно пропустить, а не отклонить). И вот почему. С одной стороны, мне кажется, что они скорее смахивают на способ решения, а не на вопрос. Но с другой стороны, они всё же конкретизируют область вопрос; правда я не уверен, что их выбор всегда однозначен.

На мой взгляд, их стоит оставлять только если есть (или ожидается) большое количество вопросов с меткой [git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), и требуется как-то их разделить на более мелкие подметки.

Comment: Проблема в том, что ссылки были релевантны и до правки. Обратите внимание на историю изменений вики: ссылки ведут на те же вопросы, что и до правки, но при этом накручивают счётчик просмотров для автора ссылок. Это выглядело бы нормальным, если автором всех вопросов или ответов являлся пользователь, опубликовавший ссылки, но в данной ситуации автор правки пытается выехать в том числе за счёт чужих вопросов и ответов. Не стану отрицать полезность ответов опубликованных самим автором правки, но самопиар, на мой взгляд, излишен.

Comment: Проблема же разбиения метки `git` на подметки заключается в том, что новые вопросы могут быть заданы с использованием только подметок, и не попадут в выдачу экспертам, фильтрующим вопросы по метке `git`. Да, Git - комплексный инструмент, и каждая его команда имеет множество опций и режимов работы, но, на мой взгляд, это не повод вводить по метке для каждой команды. Это всё равно что вводить по метке на каждый вид операторов в каком-нибудь языке программирования: вряд ли здесь найдутся эксперты по конкретному оператору, плохо разбирающиеся в других.

Comment: `если есть (или ожидается) большое количество вопорсов с меткой git` - если мы хотим, чтобы популярность и полезность RU.SO росла, то стоит навести порядок заранее. Более аргументированно об актуальности меток смотрите в моем ответе.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если автор вопроса не знает, какой командой решается его задача, то он метку команды всё равно не поставит. Выходит, что идёт рассчёт на то, что кто-то метку в вопрос добавит. А если решений несколько, или порсто нужно несколько разных команд для получения результата, то несколько меток?

Comment: @Qwertiy для совсем новых пользователей это все-таки увеличивает шанс на использование релевантных меток сразу. В крайнем случае набегут редакторы и проставят то, что нужно. Я обычно вижу и сам ставлю те метки, которые составляют существенную часть **проблемы** или решения.

Comment: @Qwertiy гораздо больше возможностей метки дают уже освоившимся пользователям. По ним можно почитать wiki, найти и изучить лучшие вопросы. Таким образом, метки помогают хранить, находить и получать знания.

Comment: @Qwertiy вон, пользователь с 11 репы сам проставил в свой вопрос  git, github, git-push, git-commit, atlassian-sourcetree. Форматирование, впрочем, не удалось. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31066005/1