# Нужны ли метки по командам Git?

Tags: поддержка, метки, удаление-метки

Примеры: [git-revert](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-revert), [git-reset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reset), [git-diff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-diff), да их море:

[image: Команды Git]

Кажется, что нет, ведь отвечать на вопросы по меткам будут люди, разбирающиеся в самом Git, вряд ли есть узкие специалисты по каким-то отдельным командам.

Аргументов «за» самостоятельно придумать не смог. Может кто-нибудь объяснить необходимость наличия меток? Или они всё же не нужны?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это (в основном) я наплодил. Я понемногу наполняю их описаниями и хорошими вопросами. В последнее время дело движется медленнее, т.к. много задач по работе + уходит время на модерацию.

Это достаточно подробно обсуждалось, правда в другом аспекте: [Самореклама в описании меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/568/181472). Пожалуйста, прочитайте ответ там. Если возникнут дополнительные вопросы - задавайте тут.

По каждой из меток, которые есть на экране, я могу привести пару десятков хороших вопросов, которые скорее всего уже заданы на SO, SU, SF, Linux&Unix, Ubuntu, OS X и других сайтах раздробленного англоязычного SE. Так что метки считаю вполне уместными.

Аналогичный вопрос на Мете SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266221/2790048

Answer (score 0):

Если оставить такие метки, то будет удобно искать по ним.
Наверняка есть специалисты глубоко разбирающиеся в Git. Всю область конечно не охватить.
Наверняка есть люди, которым приходилось часто применять те или иные команды.
И в случае оставления меток, такие специалисты смогут на них ответить.