# Следует ли отмечать вопросы-переводы общими?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правила, перевод-содержимого

Если участник считает, что хорошо бы было перевести и опубликовать вопрос и ответы к нему с англоязычного (или любого друго) Stack Overflow, следует ли отмечать такой вопрос и ответ как общие?

Есть ли какие-то дополнительные требования или рекомендации к таким вопросам и ответам?

Comment: Кстати, а почему этот вопрос стал актуален? Вопрос от анонимного участника? Кто-то отметил тревогой перевод?

Comment: Это мой вопрос к сообществу. Планирую опубликовать несколько переводов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### В этом нет необходимости, можно оставлять авторскими

Этот вопрос уже обсуждался: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/71/181472

Моё собственное мнение:

Вполне допустимо оставлять вопрос и ответы «авторскими», не общими. Перевод технической документации — это тоже труд, он требует времени и усилий. Чтобы качественно перевести, нужно вникнуть в предмет вопроса достаточно глубоко, особенно если нужно собрать кусочки решения из множества ответов.

Если мы начнем судить о мере авторского вклада в ответах, то добрую половину придется делать общими. Большинство решений, предлагаемых в ответах, не были разработаны авторами этих ответов специально для заданного вопроса. Часто это крупицы знаний из книг, документации, собственного опыта, поисковой выдачи. В чем тогда разница между «когда-то прочитал книгу, понял и теперь могу дать ответ» и «когда-то прочитал ответ на StackOverflow, понял и теперь перевёл на другой язык, чтобы дать ответ»? Я не вижу разницы.

Процитирую также участника Discord:

> Если вы боитесь обвинений в "воровстве" репутации, то можете отмечать свои вопросы и ответы как "общие". Но опасения безосновательны: перевод, особенно качественный перевод — это тоже труд, и у вас есть полное право на достойное вознаграждение.

#### Дополнительные рекомендации:

- Как правило, различные варианты решения разбросаны по нескольким ответам. Думаю, что лучше собирать их в один ответ под разными заголовками, при этом выстраивая некоторую структуру. В результате получится скорее не перевод, а ваш авторский обзор решений.
- Иногда принятый и/или самый популярный ответ устарел и больше не решает проблему. Предлагаемые варианты решения нужно проверять, а не просто копипастить.
- Возвращайтесь к переведенным текстам. Если узнали что-то, что может их улучшить — улучшайте. Нет никакой необходимости хранить точный перевод, мы же не архив.
- Очень важный момент: из уважения к авторам оригинальных ответов (и следуя лицензии), в переводе обязательно нужно указать автора и дать ссылку на оригинал. Если только вы не свой ответ переводите и если оригинал не является целиком цитатой откуда-то ещё.
- Кстати, можно сделать и обратную ссылку. Я обычно оставляю комментарий-ссылку с текстом вроде "This answer has been translated into Russian for Ru.SO". Авторы радуются.