# Недопонимание при переносе вопросов из http://clubs.ya.ru/yandex-tank/

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка-продукта-на-so

Привет.

У [yandex-tank](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-tank)-а, опенсорсного инструмента, есть несколько ресурсов:

- сам репозиторий https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank
- чат https://gitter.im/yandex/yandex-tank, где обсуждаем проблемы, оперативно пытаемся помочь внешним людям.
- клуб в ярушке http://clubs.ya.ru/yandex-tank/, в котором раньше публиковали анонсы и отвечаем на заданные людьми вопросы.

Вики у нас нет. Клуб как база знаний нас не устраивает - хочется нормального поиска, поддержки тегов, голосовалки и всего прочего что есть у stackoverflow. Есть желание перенести вопросы которые попадались нам чаще всего, а также те, в ответах на которые проясняется логика работы танка - перенести к вам, а клуб заколотить гвоздями.

Переносом занимаюсь я, беру вопрос из клуба и публикую его с самоответом. На этом этапе у нас с вами началось непонимание друг друга.
Николай @Nicolas собрал резюме (большое ему спасибо):

> Ребятам не понравилось, что информация:
>
> 1. Просто скопирована один в один.
> 2. Ответы не исчерпывающие.
>
> Я очень много общался с ребятами, которые сами не принимают активного участия в жизни сообщества, но каждый день по много раз попадают на Stack Overflow (SO) из поиска. По их мнению, самая большая польза от SO на любом языке заключается в том, что только на SO можно найти не просто развернутое объяснение проблемы, а реальный опыт использования «живым человеком» и основанные на нем советы. Было бы здорово, если бы при переносе базы знаний она была бы дополнена именно этой самой экспертизой. В обратном случае, к сожалению, с большой вероятностью, сообщество не примет такие знания.

Про копирование: планируется сделать stackoverflow единственным местом хранения этих вопросов. Дописывать вопросы заданные людьми в более развернутом виде чем нам их задали, заново повторив проблемы, мы думаю можем.

По второму пункту - ответы у нас пишут нагрузочные тестировщики, то есть это самый настоящий реальный опыт использования инструмента. Что касается экспертизы, то видимо здесь играет роль формат вопросов - обычно они касаются возможностей инструмента, и ответ в таких случаях как правило однозначный. Если бы речь шла о вопросах "Как мне лучше поступить в ..." - конечно, ответы были бы в виде "я пробовал jmeter с семплером .., получил то и то, затем перешел на  tsung, наткнулся на такие-то проблемы", но такие вопросы в клубе задают намного реже.

Пока писал пост, в чате дополнительно разъяснили какие вопросы и ответы считаются хорошими.

Формулировки вопросов и ответов пересмотрю. Вот [такой формат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469510/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-instances-%D0%B8-rps-schedule-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0) годится?
Что еще мы можем упускать?

Надеюсь, претензии по поводу спама, рекламы коммерческого продукта и дублировании информации я снял.

Upd: перенесенные вопросы скрыл в клубе ярушки

Comment: В чате высказывались мнения, что Вы должны помечать эти вопросы как общие (community wiki)

Comment: Окей. В любом случае, если ответ официальный, имеет смысл об этом упоминать (хотя бы в профиле, замечание об аффилированности). Ну и было бы замечательно, если вы останетесь на сайте, и будете отвечать на вопросы по вашему тегу (и, конечно, при желании не только по нему). Эксперты нам нужны.

Comment: в тему: [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange vs. commercial products](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133522/137096)

Comment: @Oceinic: я против. Человек обладает реальными знаниями и тратит усилия на организацию и сохранение этих знаний. Это реальный вклад в базу знаний и он должен вознаграждаться репутацией.

Answer (score 10):

Я считаю, здесь действуют все те же правила и рекомендации, что и для перевода вопросов с других языков:

- [Стоит ли переводить вопросы и ответы с англоязычного SO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70/181472) (да)
- [Следует ли отмечать вопросы-переводы общими?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1156/181472) (нет)

То чем вы занимаетесь — это организация знаний. Здорово, что все вопросы взяты из реальной практики. Но стандарты на Stack Overflow на русском наверняка несколько отличаются, поэтому вопросы могут нуждаться в некоторой доработке:

- По возможности конкретная задача или проблема
- Можно воспроизвести
- Минимальное количество кода, которым можно воспроизвести
- Читаемый код и текст вопроса (markdown к вашим услугам)

Что, пожалуй, не стоит переносить — так это различные опросы и обзоры фич (если у вас такие есть).

По поводу афиллированности я поддержу предложение VladD: оставьте хотя бы в профиле замечание о том, что вы причастны к разработке Yandex.Tank. Если вы будете рекомендовать Tank в каком-то вопросе о нагрузочном тестировании в целом, тогда можно и прямо об этом написать. (Когда у нас появятся такие вопросы...)

И ещё раз, добро пожаловать.

---

Кстати, пока что получается, что информация дублирована. Это не вызовет проблем с индексацией в поисковиках?

---

В будущем хотелось бы, чтобы opensource-продукты мы встречали как-то мягче )

Comment: Профиль обновил.

Comment: Если сейчас удалю вопросы которые выглядят коротко оформленными - не сработает ли какая-нибудь проверка, что пользователя r2d2  нужно заблокировать? :)

Comment: @r2d2 да нормальные вопросы, оставляйте все. Я прочитал, ничего непонятного не было.

Comment: обзоры фич нам нужно придумать где публиковать, но это точно не здесь.

Comment: по поводу индексации - и яндекс и гугл оперативно обновляют индексы, поэтому после удаления страницы она довольно быстро вымоется оттуда

Comment: @r2d2: краткий перечень фич будет уместен в описании метки.

Comment: дописал, очень кратенько не получилось.

Comment: скрыл перенесенные вопросы из публичного доступа в клубе

Comment: @r2d2: в итоге 9 вопросов получилось?

Comment: @r2d2: кстати, если понадобится где-нибудь дать ссылку на ru.SO, чтобы здесь искали вопросы и задавали новые, то `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-tank`, `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=yandex-tank`

Comment: В клубе есть еще несколько вопросов, которые стоит перенести, как будет свободное время, оформлю по всем правилам. Большая часть того что там осталось либо неактуальна, либо просто не стоит переноса. Ссылки добавил в описание клуба