# Допустима ли загрузка FAQ в виде массового самоотвечания?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, справка, поддержка-продукта-на-so

Хочется выгрузить на SO накопившуюся внутри базу вопросов/ответов.

Я нашёл на в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) что самоотвечать можно и даже приветствуется. Можно ли таким образом самоотвечать на большое количество вопросов (около 500)?

Если нет - то как правильно это делать?

Comment: можно, но нужно быть готовым к тому, что вопросы могут быть заминусованы и закрыты другими пользователями и, как следствие, удалены.

Comment: надо же понять какого плана вопросы

Comment: Я работаю в YDB. Недавно мы выпустили базу в OpenSource, а до этого она долго работала внутри компании и накопилась база вопросов от внутренних пользователей, которые могут быть полезны сообществу. Примеры заголовков вопросов:
"Можно ли загрузить в YDB данные в формате CSV?", "Как правильно записать большое число строк в динамическую таблицу?", "Что указать в опциях ReadTable для колонки типа string?", "Как TTL на колонке Uint64 через YQL?". К каждому вопросу есть тело вопроса с пояснением проблемы. Публиковать вопросы планирую под тегом ydb https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ydb

Comment: это никак не отменяет того, что я указал в первом комментарии.

Comment: Да, это понятно. @Dmitry спрашивал какого плана вопросы. А были уже прецеденты подобных выгрузок, есть ли сложившаяся практика? Например: "растянуть процесс и заводить вопросы по 10 в день, чтобы не отправлять миллион уведомлений скопом" или наоборот: "Постараться сделать всё за 1 день, чтобы сообщество получило одно уведомление в ежедневной рассылке, а не каждый день"?

Comment: @rekby, можешь поискать про `tank` или что-то подобное: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1871/186999

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну вообще, YQL штука хорошая - думаю, можно было бы запостить.

Только вот завалить всё 500 вопросами сразу - так себе идея. Думаю, по 2-3 вопроса в день (ну может чуть больше) было бы нормально. Ну и вопросы с ответами должны быть нормального качества.

Comment: Спасибо.

Ответ отмечу/напишу по итогам того как наполнение базы пройдёт, когда будет понятно что и как сообществом принимается.

Answer (score 2):

Ничего про то, что вы пишете не знаю, но вот примеры тематического самоотвечания есть хорошие. Обратите внимание на пользователя [Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt). Эксперт в `svg`, авторские статьи и все в этом духе. Можно брать пример "как надо".

И соглашусь с @Qwertiy, что залить все 500 вопросов разом, будет жестко)