# Перевод простых вопросов с enSO

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

Посмотрел на [наиболее заплюсованные вопросы по Java на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) и понял, что для многих из них на ruSO нет ассоциаций. Да, на мете уже был [вопрос про перевод вопросов с enSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70/227016), но хочу ещё раз уточнить.

В частности, например, интересует [вопрос про преобразование `ArrayList` в массив](https://stackoverflow.com/q/157944/5812238). Наверняка на ruSO есть много вопросов, где неявно дан ответ на этот вопрос, но если [поискать в Google](https://google.ru/search?q=java+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+arraylist+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

> java получить arraylist из массива

то среди первых пяти сайтов в выдаче не будет вопроса на ruSO. Я же правильно понимаю, что можно переводить этот и другие простые вопросы?

Comment: Переводите любые вопросы, которые могут кому-то помочь. Предложенный вопрос, видимо, очень популярен, значит стоит его перевести. Если есть желание, конечно.

Comment: Имхо стоит закрыть как [будликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70), ибо простой вопрос есть подмножество просто вопросов.

Comment: @Skyrocker не узнаю вас в гриме.

Comment: Diraria, конечно переводите, особенно популярные. Только не стоит переводить дословно. Часто хорошие идеи размазаны по нескольким ответам, например по вашей ссылке их аж 32. Лучше собрать из них лучшее, структурировать и оформить одним ответом.

Comment: Да, и уж точно не стоит переводить комментарии (кто-то так делал, не помню, кто).

Comment: @NickVolynkin [профиль - все действия - комментарии - самые старые](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/207618/skyrocker?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=17). Читаем.

Comment: @alexolut да у меня есть и более прямые инструменты. Это так, шутка была. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin другие (с кривыми инструментами) теперь тоже [будут знать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5878/176217)!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Решил обновить виртуальный облик.